# Find & du to calculate total size vs xargs

Tags: cygwin, find, xargs

Can someone confirm that the following one liner will produce the total human readable size of all the directories which FIND locates as having log in the name?

```
find -type d -name *log* | du -hcs
```

Answer (score 0):

Ready?

`find . -type d -name '*log*' -print0 | xargs -0 du -hcs`

- Wrap the `*log*` in single quotes or else the shell will expand it before `find` sees it.
- Use `-print0` to separate the find output by null characters for `xargs`
- use `xargs -0` to put each null-separated filename from `find` into the command line of `du`

Easy, right? :)

Comment: They both seem to do the job - yours outputs each directory as it finds it though where mine only prints the total. Not sure which one is 'better', I suppose it depends on the need.

Comment: Actually strike that comment :) -  both came up with drastically different numbers hrm.

Comment: Still looking for feedback here on why the two values are different?

Comment: Can you post a tarball of your test-case directory tree somewhere?

Comment: Oh!  It's because "du" doesn't take its input from the command line.  In the original command line, the output of `find` goes to the standard input of `du` and gets ignored.  As a result, `du -hcs` reports the total size of the whole current directory.  The `xargs` in the answer moves those filenames from standard input to the command line where `du` will see them.  In my `/var` on cygwin, the command line from the question gives the same output as `du -hcs` without the `find`: `79M .`.  The command line from the answer gives `1.1M ./log`, indicating it only processed ./log.

Comment: yeah it's easy to see that the output of `anycommand | du -hcs` would be exactly the same as `du -hcs`, so the OP's command is wrong in many ways and doesn't report the total size of log folders at all

Answer (score 0):

Your one-liner has two major issues:

- The command `find | du` passes the output of `find` to the stdin of `du`. However, `du` completely ignores the standard input, so the `find` filter is completely ignored, and the command you provided is in fact equivalent to `du -hcs`. The solution is to use [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Invoking-xargs), which passes the list of files as arguments to `du`, or `du --files0-from=-` (GNU coreutils).
- You need to [quote](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) the asterisks in your file name pattern either with backslashes (`\*log\*`) or with single quotes (`'*log*'`), otherwise your shell will try to perform [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and `find` will possibly not see the asterisks at all.

Some more improvements:

- In case of matches inside matched directories like `./log/log/`, both `./log/` and `./log/log/` would be passed to `du`. The second directory would be ignored by `du -s`, but you can increase performance of the `find` command by adding the `-prune` action. It will make sure that `find` does not further descend into matched directories.
- I'm adding `-print0` (and `-0` to `xargs`) to avoid potential problems with e.g. newlines in file names, [see serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/994723/dropping-the-print0-and-0-flags-from-find-and-xargs).
- I'm adding the path (`.`) to make the `find` command compatible to POSIX (and BSD).

This is the final one-liner:

```sh
find . -type d -name '*log*' -prune -print0 | xargs -0 du -hcs
```

Keep in mind that `-name` is case-sensitive. Personally I almost always use `-iname`, which is case-insensitive.

---

Additional note: if you're using GNU coreutils' `du`, you can use its `--files0-from=-` option and pass the file paths directly to `du`, omitting `xargs`. According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#du-invocation), ”this is useful when the list of file names is so long that it may exceed a command line length limitation.“

```sh
find . -type d -name '*log*' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hcs
```