# Two ways - two different results

Tags: command-line, find

I ran two seperate commands each one produced a different number. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
find -type d -name *log* | du -hcs

find . -type d -name '*log*' -print0 | xargs -0 du -hcs
```

Comment: Related: [Find & du to calculate total size vs xargs](http://superuser.com/questions/728690/find-du-to-calculate-total-size-vs-xargs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that the downvoter(s) thought that the way to figure out why was

```
man du
```

and wondered why you hadn't read the manual.

Ironically, whilst this is indeed true for the BSDs, on Linux distributions this isn't the way to find out, because the GNU manual page is missing some fairly basic stuff.  Linux users have to run

```
info coreutils du
```

to see documentation with one very important sentence in.

It's the second sentence (third in OpenBSD) of the manual page for the BSD `du` command.

So even though your wildcard — in your command rather than the corrected version that was given to you in an answer — is (potentially) expanded incorrectly in your `find` command, that doesn't make a single hap'orth of difference.  **Whatever** your `find` command writes to its standard output, it is entirely ignored by the `du` command.

From the manual, which explicitly states what is happening, combined with what was *already stated* in that answer in its third bullet point, it should be blindingly obvious why you're seeing different behaviours and results between your command and the corrected one.  Prepare to kick yourself.  ☺

### Further reading

- [`du`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html).  MacOS 10 manual pages.  Apple corporation.
- [`du`](http://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?du(1)).  *FreeBSD 9.2 manual pages*.  2012-11-04.
- [`du`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?du).  *NetBSD 6.1.3 manual pages*.  2006-09-24.
- [`du`](http://openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=du).  *OpenBSD 5.4 manual pages*.  2014-02-14.
- [`du`](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=du).  *DragonFly BSD 3.7 manual pages*.  1994-04-01.